# How to Rig a Stiff Leg?

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm about to build an IK/FK rig for a character with stiff legs. In other words, the knees don't bend. Ever. Other than that, it'll be a complete rig, minus face controls.

In the interests of not reinventing the wheel, I thought I'd ask if anyone else has ever built a rig like this or if any pre-existing rigging tool (Rigify, Auto-rig) has an option for stiff legs.